# Is it possible to get the network type from a Firefox for android addon?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to develop an addon to Firefox for Android, which can get the info whether the current network link is 2G/3G/4G or wifi, and send this information as a http header to web server. I know it's possible to get such an information with native Java code. Is there some Firefox addon API that can provide this information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `nsINetworkLinkService`

```
// Where Cc and Ci are shortcuts for Components.classes and .interfaces
let network = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/network-link-service;1"].
              getService(Ci.nsINetworkLinkService);
console.log(network.linkType);
```

For values of `.linkType`, see the [interface definition](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsINetworkLinkService.idl#14), e.g. `.linkType == Ci.nsINetworkLinkService.LINK_TYPE_4G`.

This service should be available on all platforms, but some platforms (e.g. OSX at the time of writing) may only have a stub always returning either `LINK_TYPE_UNKNOWN` or outright throwing an exception when accessing the `.linkType` property.

On Android it should always return sane values though, as long as Android itself returns sane values.

Comment: thanks for your help. but it seems it has been removed due to some reason: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsINetworkLinkService

Comment: I just tested that with Aurora (31) and `linkType` is set to the correct value. Maybe the documentation is outdated.

Comment: The docs are wrong. [It was re-implemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=939680) in mozilla28 (Firefox 28) apparently.

Comment: Aha, that's so great! Thanks a lot!